# Unable to obtain chromedriver.exe using Selenium Manager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Error:
`Message: Unable to obtain chromedriver.exe using Selenium Manager; Message: Unsuccessful command executed: /var/task/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager --browser chrome --output json; Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
   
   def do_GET(self):
       self.send_response(200)
       self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
       self.end_headers()

       try:
           service = Service(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')
           options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
           options.add_argument('--headless')
           driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
           driver.get('https://www.example.com/')
           driver.save_screenshot("screenshot_example.png")
           
       except Exception as e:
           # Print the exception error
           self.wfile.write(f'{str(e)}'.encode('utf-8'))

       self.wfile.write('Hello, world!'.encode('utf-8'))
       return
```

I tried changing `./chromedriver.exe` in many different ways already with/without `.exe` and `/` or the `./`

Answer (score 3):

I've same issue while updating my previous code, and here is my solution:

Find the `chromedriver` path. In my case, run `dpkg -L chromium-chromedriver` and get `/usr/bin/chromedriver`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Add service
service = Service(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Test environment:

> - OS: Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit
> - Python: 3.9
> - selenium: 4.12.0
> - chromedriver: 113.0.5672.95

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the key *`executable_path`* along with absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447). You just need to pass the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* as follows:

```
service = Service('./chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Comment: nope, that didn't work - gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use `chromedriver.exe` on a Linux machine, but that is a Windows file extension. On Mac / Linux, the file is just `chromedriver`.

As of `selenium` `4.10.0`, (where the driver manager is now included and out of beta), you can just do this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```