# NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the below error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

I am trying to launch chrome browser. Below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Below is working for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

But, I want to launch without webdriver manager. It was working a few days back.

Is there a way to launch chrome without webdriver manager.

---

I have selenium 4.12.0 and webdriver manager 4.0.0 in my system.

Could someone please assist me with this?

Comment: This is working for me. But, i want to launch without webdriver manager. It was working a few days back.

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

Comment: Please include that in your original post and not in the comments.

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76444831/unable-to-obtain-chromedriver-exe-using-selenium-manager

Comment: Make sure your directory does not include any `chromedriver.exe`

Comment: Yes. I don't have chromedriver.exe in any directory.